# Is it possible to restore single PostgreSQL database to PITR?

Tags: postgresql, restore

I have PostgreSQL instance with n databases on it.

Is it possible to restore just a single database using PITR ?

```
# restore
tar xvfz /var/lib/postgresql/db_file_backup.tar.gz -C /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/

# add recovery.conf
nano /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/recovery.conf

  restore_command = 'cp /var/lib/postgresql/pg_log_archive/%f %p'
  recovery_target_time = '2018-02-22 15:20:00 EST'

# start DB
sudo systemctl start postgresql@10-main
```

I see that `pg_restore` contains `dbname` parameter. But it's logical. I need to restore to specific Point-In-Time.

```
pg_restore --help pg_restore restores a PostgreSQL database from an archive created by pg_dump. Usage:  pg_restore [OPTION]... [FILE] General options:  -d, --dbname=NAME        connect to database name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have that.

PITR requires a file system level backup and recovery, and both encompass the whole cluster. I am not saying it is theoretically impossible, but no such functionality exists.